# Add elements to the end of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, indexof

I am trying to solve a challenge from jshero.net.

The challenge is:

> *Write a function add that adds an element to the end of an array. However, the element should only be added if it is not already in the array. `add([1, 2], 3)` should return `[1, 2, 3]` and `add([1, 2], 2)` should return `[1, 2]`.*

The problem is for [Array:indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: have you read [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or better [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)?

Comment: 1. Flatten the inner array (flat at any depth .eg shown below with depth 4).

   function add(array, number) {
      const flattendArray = array.flat(Infinity);
      flattendArray.push(number);
      return  [...new Set(flattendArray)]
    }
 console.log(add([1, 2, [3, 4, [4, 6, [7, 8, [8, 9, 10]]]]], 11));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the number exists in the array

```js
function add(arr, number) {
  if (arr.includes(number)) return arr;
  else return [...arr, number];

}

console.log(add([1,2], 3));
console.log(add([1,2], 2));
```

You can also use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
function add(arr, number) {
  if (arr.indexOf(number) > -1) return arr;
  else return [...arr, number];

}

console.log(add([1,2], 3));
console.log(add([1,2], 2));
```

Comment: IT WORKED . Thank you very much. It ran perfectly.

Comment: @DefNotBruceWayne Alternatively, you can call `arr.indexOf(number) !== -1`, if you wanted another way to do this. This is the more language-agnostic approach, the one most people unfamiliar with JS would go with.

Comment: @Melchia , what downvote? I never downvoted anything

Comment: @Melchia this solution won't work if you have depth of inner array more than 1. Thanks but great work!!

Comment: @khizer Where is it stated in the question that we're dealing with multi layer arrays ?

Comment: @Melchia It isn't stated but solution should be generic IMO. Just a good way :) plus what will be the solution in case of console.log(add([2,2], 2)); => it should be [2] only ;)

Comment: How do you know that we're not trying to preserve the original array? If the question was just to remove duplicates from the array we would've used Set directly! just stick to the question!

Comment: This question is clearly a duplicate, so it should be simply marked as one, instead of repeating such a basic answer :)